# Python server only working on local wifi

Tags: python, python-2.7, network-programming, ip, server

The code:

```
import socket, threading

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server.bind(("my ipv4 from ipconfig", 12))

server.listen(5)

def client_handler(client_socket):
    request = client_socket.recv(100)

    print "[*] Received: " + request

    client_socket.close()

while True:
    client, addr = server.accept()
    print "[*] Accepted connection from: %s:%d" % (addr[0], addr[1])
    servert = threading.Thread(target=client_handler, args=(client,))
    servert.start()
```

So the server seems to work fine locally but if i ask my friend on a different network to connect, it doesn't connect. I tried port forwarding from the router 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSUir.png ( cant post img apparently cause my_reputation < 10)

I also tried using the ip i get from the whatismyip website, but i get the error:

> error: [Errno 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context

Any ideas on what i could do so other people can connect? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you are setting your forward to the same IPs.  Your WAN IP should be your public IP (what you get from whatismyip) and your LAN IP should be that of your local machine (what you get from ipconfig).

Comment: Try using 0.0.0.0:<some port number> as your IP address and check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're trying to access your server from outside your LAN, you ought to use 0.0.0.0 as your IP address while creating your socket object. 0.0.0.0 usually means the default route (the route to "the rest of" the internet, aside from routes in your local network etc.). If you use the IP address allotted by DCHP (in your case, the router), the devices connected to the network (router) is only aware of the fact that your IP address is what you get in $ifconfig command, a private IP address which the client is unaware

Comment: so if i use "0.0.0.0" Which ip will i have to give to the client? the public one? Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, the public one, and you need to make sure your NAT port forwards that correctly to your private IP.

Comment: Yes and if you're using a router, check for the bridge function on your router, it will forward all WAN traffic to LAN port so you could use public IP on your device at LAN port directly.

Comment: Dude last question, at the client script: client.connect(("", port)) which ip do i enter, it doesnt accept the public one

Comment: No I meant the client on the other network . which sends the packets to the server

Comment: See what @Laogeodritt said